# Java icons return to default position

Tags: java, layout, jlabel

I've written a GUI application, and if I drag a JLabel and drop it onto an empty area, it stays where I dropped it. However, if I drop it onto another JLabel, the JLabels appear as if the layout manager has moved them back to the default position, even though I set the locations for all of them.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Vector;
public class DragnDrop {
    static JFrame window=new JFrame("Drag n Drop");
    static JPanel content=new JPanel();
    static JMenu file=new JMenu("File");
    static JMenuItem clear=new JMenuItem("New");
    static JMenuItem quit=new JMenuItem("Quit");
    static JMenu edit=new JMenu("Edit");
    static JMenuItem addm=new JMenuItem("Add mole");
    static JMenuItem addh=new JMenuItem("Add hole");
    static ImageIcon hole=new ImageIcon("hole.png");
    static ImageIcon mole=new ImageIcon("mole.png");
    static JMenuBar menubar=new JMenuBar();
    static Vector<JLabel> draggables=new Vector<JLabel>();
    static Vector<Point> dragpoints=new Vector<Point>();
    static Vector<Boolean> morh=new Vector<Boolean>(); //true if mole
    static Vector<Integer> hcounts=new Vector<Integer>();
    static Vector<Integer> mcounts=new Vector<Integer>();
    public static class DragHandler extends MouseAdapter{
        int xDisp;
        int yDisp;
        int curr;
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            JLabel tmp=(JLabel) e.getComponent();
            curr=(draggables.indexOf(tmp));
            xDisp = dragpoints.elementAt(curr).x - tmp.getLocation().x;
            yDisp = dragpoints.elementAt(curr).y - tmp.getLocation().y+63;
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
            JLabel tmp=(JLabel) e.getComponent();
            JLabel tmp2 = null;
            int toRemove=0;
            int replacement=0;
            boolean remove=false;
            toRemove=draggables.indexOf(tmp);
            for(int a=0;a<draggables.size();a++){
                if(tmp.getLocation().x>=dragpoints.elementAt(a).x&&tmp.getLocation().x<=dragpoints.elementAt(a).x+draggables.elementAt(a).getWidth()){
                    if(tmp.getLocation().y>=dragpoints.elementAt(a).y&&tmp.getLocation().y<=dragpoints.elementAt(a).y+draggables.elementAt(a).getHeight()){
                        if(draggables.elementAt(a)!=tmp&&morh.elementAt(toRemove)==true){
                            Integer temp=mcounts.elementAt(a);
                            temp=Integer.valueOf(temp.intValue()+1);
                            mcounts.setElementAt(temp,a);
                            remove=true;
                            replacement=a;
                            tmp2=(JLabel) draggables.elementAt(a);
                            break;
                        }
                        else if(draggables.elementAt(a)!=tmp){
                            Integer temp=hcounts.elementAt(a);
                            temp=Integer.valueOf(temp.intValue()+1);
                            hcounts.setElementAt(temp,a);
                            remove=true;
                            replacement=a;
                            tmp2=(JLabel) draggables.elementAt(a);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(remove==true){
                if(hcounts.elementAt(replacement).intValue()!=0){
                    tmp2.setText(hcounts.elementAt(replacement)+"H");
                }
                if(mcounts.elementAt(replacement).intValue()!=0){
                    if(tmp2.getText()==null){
                        tmp2.setText(mcounts.elementAt(replacement)+"M");
                    }
                    else{
                        tmp2.setText(tmp2.getText()+"  "+mcounts.elementAt(replacement)+"M");
                    }
                }
                draggables.removeElementAt(toRemove);
                dragpoints.removeElementAt(toRemove);
                morh.removeElementAt(toRemove);
                mcounts.removeElementAt(toRemove);
                hcounts.removeElementAt(toRemove);
                tmp.setVisible(false);
            }
            else{
                dragpoints.setElementAt(tmp.getLocation(), curr);
            }
            content.validate();
            for(int a=0;a<draggables.size();a++){
                draggables.elementAt(a).setLocation(dragpoints.elementAt(a));
                System.out.println(draggables.elementAt(a).getLocation().x+" "+draggables.elementAt(a).getLocation().y); //debugging purposes
            }
        }
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
            JLabel tmp = (JLabel) e.getComponent();
            PointerInfo tmppi=MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
            Point pt=tmppi.getLocation();
            tmp.setLocation(pt.x-xDisp,pt.y-yDisp);
        }
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
        }
    }
    public static class AddMHandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JLabel tmp=new JLabel(mole);
            DragHandler drag=new DragHandler();
            tmp.setLocation(0,0);
            tmp.addMouseListener(drag);
            tmp.addMouseMotionListener(drag);
            tmp.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
            tmp.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            content.add(tmp, 0);
            content.validate();
            for(int a=0;a<draggables.size();a++){
                draggables.elementAt(a).setLocation(dragpoints.elementAt(a));
            }
            draggables.add(tmp);
            dragpoints.add(new Point(0,0));
            draggables.elementAt(draggables.size()-1).setLocation(dragpoints.elementAt(draggables.size()-1));
            morh.add(new Boolean(true));
            mcounts.add(new Integer(1));
            hcounts.add(new Integer(0));
        }
    }
    public static class AddHHandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JLabel tmp=new JLabel(hole);
            DragHandler drag=new DragHandler();
            tmp.setLocation(0,0);
            tmp.addMouseListener(drag);
            tmp.addMouseMotionListener(drag);
            tmp.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
            tmp.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            content.add(tmp, 0);
            content.validate();
            for(int a=0;a<draggables.size();a++){
                draggables.elementAt(a).setLocation(dragpoints.elementAt(a));
            }
            draggables.add(tmp);
            dragpoints.add(new Point(0,0));
            draggables.elementAt(draggables.size()-1).setLocation(dragpoints.elementAt(draggables.size()-1));
            morh.add(new Boolean(false));
            hcounts.add(new Integer(1));
            mcounts.add(new Integer(0));
        }
    }
    public static class ClearHandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            content.removeAll();
            content.validate();
        }
    }
    public static class QuitHandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        clear.addActionListener(new ClearHandler());
        file.add(clear);
        quit.addActionListener(new QuitHandler());
        quit.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
        quit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q, ActionEvent.META_MASK));
        file.add(quit);
        addm.addActionListener(new AddMHandler());
        addm.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_M);
        addm.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_M, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
        edit.add(addm);
        addh.addActionListener(new AddHHandler());
        addh.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_H);
        addh.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_H, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
        edit.add(addh);
        menubar.add(file);
        menubar.add(edit);
        window.setJMenuBar(menubar);
        window.setSize(500, 500);
        window.setLocation(0, 0);
        window.setContentPane(content);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use static variables!!! This indicates a poor design of your class. Restructure your code and get rid of the static variables.

Answer (score 1):

I really can't tell what you are trying to do with your code. For example I can't figure out why you have two add handlers. The code looks very similar.

> However, if I drop it onto another JLabel, the JLabels appear as if the layout manager has moved them back to the default position

Normally when you drag components around a panel you need to use a `null layout` so the components will stay where you dragged them.

In your case you seem to be using a JPanel which uses a FlowLayout as the default layout manager so when you revalidate the panel the components location is reset by the layout manager.

For a null layout you need to use:

```
panel.setLayout(null);
```

For simple dragging logic you can use the following:

```
public class DragListener extends MouseInputAdapter
{
    Point location;
    MouseEvent pressed;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
    {
        pressed = me;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)
    {
        Component component = me.getComponent();
        location = component.getLocation(location);
        int x = location.x - pressed.getX() + me.getX();
        int y = location.y - pressed.getY() + me.getY();
        component.setLocation(x, y);
     }
}
```

And you just add the listeners to a component using:

```
DragListener drag = new DragListener();
component.addMouseListener( drag );
component.addMouseMotionListener( drag );
```

Comment: I tried using a null layout, but nothing showed up on the window. What I don't get is why when I drag a JLabel onto an empty area, it doesn't move the JLabels back to the default location, but when I drag a JLabel onto another one, it does return them to the default location.

Comment: When you use a null layout you need to set the size and location of the component. Actually you can use the [Drag Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/) instead of the FlowLayout to help with this. `when I drag a JLabel onto an empty area, it doesn't move the JLabels back to the default location` The location is only reset when you invoke revalidate() or validate() on the panel (or if you resize the frame). I don't understand your code so I can't tell if you are doing this or not.

Comment: I do validate() every time I let go of one of the JLabels.

Comment: Sorry, I told you I don't understand your code. It is way too complicated for simply dragging. I showed you how to do it in 10 lines of code. Restructure your program, to use my suggestion and get rid of all the static variables. To learn how to better structure your code try reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Demos](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html). The demo code there show how you can do everything without static variables.